# String or list substitution in Python

Tags: python, string, list, substitution

How would I go about taking a string：

```
("h1", "h2", "h3, "h4")
```

And substituting these values with numbers `1, 2, 3, 4`?

Correspondingly, how I would I preform the same operation but on a list instead?

Comment: Are you talking about a string `"(\"h1", \"h2\", \"h3\", \"h4\")"`?  Or a list of strings?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are asking here... Are you looking to simply remove the leading 'h' from your strings? Or do you have a long string and need to replace all instances of 'h1' with '1' in it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 to_replace = ["h1","h2","h3","h4"]
 replaced = [ int(s.replace("h","")) for s in to_replace ]
```

If this is what you want.

It's not exactly clear; I'm assuming that your input is not literally a string `"(\"h1\", \"h2\", \"h3\", \"h4\")"`, but a list of strings.

And I'm not sure what you meant by your second question, as it appears to be the same as the first.

I will update my answer accordingly =)

Comment: To MikeD:  Yeah, basically that is what I want to do.  To give some context, I am trying translate R code into Python and what I am trying to do is build a multi-dimensional array out of 3 strings/lists/whatever that contain 4 elements per string/list.  I guess first off, what is better to use for building an array: a list or a string?  You'll have to please forgive my cryptic descriptions because I am a n00b with Python. :)

Comment: To Justin:  I apologize for my unclear question.  Its partially because I am not sure what it is that I am after.  I have an R script that I am trying to translate.  (I know there is rPy to handle this stuff automagically, but I am trying to learn Python by translation). What you offered looks close.  In R it reads like this:  hClasses <- as.numeric(gsub("h", "", segmentsH)).  I tried what you had but wrote it this way:  segmentsH = ["h1", "h2", "h3", "h4"] <br> hClasses = [ int(s.replace("h","")) for s in segmentsH ].Worked perfectly.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This would strip out every non-numeric character (not only `h`):

```
>>> s = ["h1", "h2" , "h3" , "h4"]
>>> [int(filter(lambda c: c.isdigit(), x)) for x in s]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

or

```
>>> s = ["x1", "b2" , "c3" , "h4"]
>>> [int(filter(lambda c: c.isdigit(), x)) for x in s]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: ChristopeD:  Thanks for this alternate solution.  This may come in handy later on in my script.  :) Appreciate your help.